# Override an array of functions as Promise

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with a form that loads data and a set of different modules depending on the data retrieved. I have an `onSubmit` event tied to the form. Some of the modules loaded adds a function that returns a Promise to a `submitHooks` array. When a user submits the form, it executes all of those functions in the Array, and continues to do its thing. For example:

```js
// submitHooks array
var submitHooks = [];

// a module loader passes in the array, and the module adds on to it. For example...
// ...
function doSomething() {
    return new Promise(function(res){
        return setTimeout(function(){ return res('something'); }, 700);
    });
}
submitHooks.push(doSomething);
// ...

// On submit...
function onSubmit() {
    Promise.all(submitHooks.map(function(sh){ return sh(); }))
        .then(function(results){
            // finish up
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            // handle error
        });
}
```

However, depending on the scenario, there could be one "override" module loaded that adds on to the `submitHooks` array and would like to prevent everything else in that array from being executed.

*Question: How would I do this? How do I prevent all other functions in that `submitHooks` array from being executed if there is an "override" function in it?*

What I tried to do is clear the `submitHooks` array, but it would only work if that "override" module was loaded last. If there were other modules loaded after it, those would still execute.

```js
function overrideAllOthers() {
    return new Promise(function(res){
     // ...
    });
}
submitHooks.length = 0;
submitHooks.push(overrideAllOthers);
// this doesn't work
```

Another way I could think of is having the modules return an object like this:

```
submitHooks.push({
    override: false,
    doSomething: function() { }
});
```

Then on the `onSubmit`, check for any `override` and execute only that. Otherwise, execute everything. Problem with this is having to modify all the existing modules, and I'm hoping I don't have to touch any of the existing modules.

Comment: if i understood correctly, you want to prevent the newly loaded modules from overriding the old ones if they match ? and say we can do this which of the two should be dropped ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak If an "override" module is loaded, prevent ALL others. I haven't considered two or more "override" modules, but if that's the case, for now we could just run one of them (any order).

Comment: You could just have a check for the override in your onSubmit before your Promise.all.  As far as I know, `Promise.all` is async, so you won't be able to prevent  certain calls in it to run.

Comment: what you mean by an `override` module ?

Comment: @Jim Yes, that's what I intended to do, but I'm trying to figure out how will it know if the array has an override. As I've mentioned, I would prefer if I don't have to modify all of the modules.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Paragraph 2 in my question.

Comment: Yes i've read the question more than once and still don't get what you mean by an override module, what is `override` in this context like module name or a module that you defined that is an `override` module, because if you're the one requesting all the modules you'd know.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Modules get loaded on the page. Which modules get loaded depends on the initial data loaded. Some of the modules will add on to the `submitHook` array which will all get executed on `onsubmit`. One particular scenario, a module will be loaded, it would add a function to the `submitHook` array, and it would like to be the only one to be executed within the array. Hope that helps.

Comment: so an `override module` is a module that prevents other modules from running so it's the only that runs ? right

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes.

Comment: You're trying to distinguish between modules based on what they do, which you can't know until your run them so that is out of the question, a solution to this is usually fixed by metadata in, your best bet is to change only the `override modules` not all modules, and have them expose an object with a property like you showed in your example instead of just a method and check if that property exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about Jim's answer, but I needed a marker from the overriding module as an indicator. Then I realized: "Wait, a function in Javascript *is* an object!" Finally, I was only able to modify just the overriding module and the submit event:

```
// overriding module

function overrideAllOthers() {
    return new Promise(function(res){
     // ...
    });
}
overrideAllOthers.override = true;
submitHooks.push(overrideAllOthers);
// ...

// event
function onSubmit() {
    var overrideHook = submitHooks.find(function(sh){ return sh.override; });
    if(overrideHook) {
        overrideHook();
    } else {
        Promise.all(submitHooks.map(function(sh){ return sh(); }))
            .then(function(results){
                // finish up
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                // handle error
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rather write `submitHooks.find(sh => sh.override)`. With the `in` operator, you'd get weird results for `overrideAllOthers.override = false;`

Comment: @Bergi Oh that's true. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check for the function in the array first.  Something like:

```
function onSubmit() {
    if(OVERRIDE_FUNCTION_EXISTS_IN_SUBMITHOOKS) { 
        return new Promise(() => OVERRIDE_FUNCTION()})
    else { 
        Promise.all(submitHooks.map(function(sh){ return sh(); }))
            .then(function(results){
                // finish up
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                // handle error
            });
}
```